# Reputation bug? (101+15+10=111?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I just registered on SE superuser and noticed, that when my first answer got accepted+upvoted, my reputation was increased to 111. Where does that number come from?

[image]

Forgive me if I am overlooking something obvious.

**EDIT regarding the comment:**
https://superuser.com/reputation shows correct information

```
total votes: 2
-- bonuses   (100)
-- 2013-08-23 rep +100  = 101       
 1    771265 (15)
 2    771265 (10)
-- 2014-06-23 rep +25   = 126       

** rep today: 25
** rep this week (2014-06-22 - 2014-06-28): 25
** rep this month (2014-06-01 - 2014-06-30): 25
** rep this quarter (2014-04-01 - 2014-06-30): 25
** rep this year (2014-01-01 - 2014-12-31): 25
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 126 :)

days represented 2
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
earned 0 reputation from suggested edits
```

EDIT 24.06.14: With a delay of about one day, reputation is now shown correctly.

Comment: It's the [su] reputation tax which you have to pay as a new user ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Outrageous! ;)

Comment: What do you see on http://superuser.com/reputation btw?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: superuser.com/reputation is correct. See edit.

Comment: Seems it's sorted out now, but usually reputation is updated immediately. Weird bug.

Comment: Yes, somewhat weird because the "upvote" was registered immediately but the "accept" wasn't (both were granted simultaneously). Whatever, since the data is correct its at best a minor problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess here, based on some log data, is a race condition where the upvote and the accept vote were registered almost exactly at the same time, causing one update to be swallowed. Such a race is improbable and rare, but possible. For those cases where this does happen, there's an automated daily job that catches these inconsistencies and fixes the reputation, which is why the number was correct after a day.

Comment: Sound explanation. I will now click Accept and Upvote as fast as possible! ;)

Comment: Good thing then that there's no reputation on a child meta :)

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, the problem has resolved itself. It was probably something related to caching.

Comment: Should I accept this "speculation" to resolve the matter? I am not much of a meta user...

Comment: @Rev1.0 You can do that or wait for an answer from a Stack Exchange employee. I'm going to assume that you won't get one any time soon though.